# Alteon 4408 issue (License Key)

Tags: switch

I have a terrible issue on Alteon 4408.

In order to recover password (I forgot my password.), I tried to search on the internet.
However, I didn't find great solution.
Finally, I entered strange environment like "cmd".
At that point, I figured out that it was a solution to recover password.

Maybe I should have tried it.. because I "clear nvram".

After that, Alteon 4408 required me to type the **license key**.

I'm so confused..
I don't have a license key;

What should I do to deal with it.
Please help me.
Thank you for reading.

The thing that switch required was below one.

---

Invalid license key

Please enter a license key (e.g. appdirector-GxtlqMwA) for device:

```
MAC address: xxxxxx
License ID : xxd-xxx-xxx
```

In case of problems please contact Radware's support.

License key:

Comment: If you don't have the license key, you will need to contact Radware support. We can't provide you a license key.

Comment: Ah ok sir. thank you.
But I want to sign up radware.com
If you have an account at radware.
Please give me how to login it.
Actually I have an account but they didn't give authorization to entering it.
Is there a reason why I didn't enter the site?...

Comment: This really is something you need to discuss with Radware, we can't help you with this.

Comment: Ok!! .. Anyway, I'll contact radware .
Thank you for giving me information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do what it says! CONTACT RADWARE SUPPORT. They're the only ones who can (re)generate your license key(s). If you erased it from persistent storage (internal drive, flash, whatever), and don't have it recorded somewhere, it's gone. We've had that problem enough times to keep our keys recorded elsewhere.

(If you're a Radware customer with an active support contract, you should be able to get your keys from the support portal. Or so I'm told.)

Comment: AHHHHHHHHHH.. Okay ㅠㅠ Thank you ..
But I have a question about http://www.radware.com/ account.
I signed up at radware web site.
But they didn't give me an authorization to log in to the internet even though I sent the email many times.
How to log in radware web site?

Comment: If you have problems accessing Radware's website you need to contact Radware. We cannot help you with this.